# Is the 're' in 'return' and 'repeat' a prefix?

Tags: prefixes

Can anybody tell me whether the 're' in 'return'and 'repeat' is a prefix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what you allow as derivation.

Synchronically, that is in English itself, the *re-* in *return* is surely a prefix, as there is also *turn* in English, from which to derive it, 're-turn'. But English has no verb 'peat' to derive 're-peat', so it can't be a product of synchronic derivation.

Taking the words' etymology, on the other hand, the *re-* in 'repeat' is also a prefix, as this verb comes from Latin *repeto, repetĕre* 'to strike again', derived from a simplex *peto, petĕre* 'to fall, to attack'.

Both verbs came to English via Old French, and not directly from Latin. Sometimes the sound changes from Latin to Old French make the original words less recognizable, like Latin *canto, cantāre* 'to sing', Old French *chanter* 'id.', English *to chant*.

Comment: I don't know if *re-* in *return* is so clearly a prefix. The Latin *tornāre* much more strongly implied turning *in a circle*, to give *return* a meaning of "come back" which isn't captured by *re-turn*, "turn again."

Comment: Well, I was just thinking about the morphology of the word. The meaning of compound verbs tend to drift a lot even in Latin itself. You will surely remember verbs like *respicio, -ĕre*, *invideo, -ēre*... from 'to see again' to 'to respect', or 'to look into(?)' to 'to envy' the distance is considerable.

Comment: Small correction: every dictionary I reference (three so far), gives *petere* to mean "seek" instead of "strike" ...